# Acesso a rota API Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, api

Estou aprendendo usar o Laravel como API Rest e fui testar pelo postman uma rota que retorna uma string, mas não estou conseguindo achar um erro. Retorna not found.

Endereço: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/ponto/

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;


Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function()
{
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'ponto'], function()
    {
        Route::get('/', function()
        {
            return 'Teste';
        });
    });
});
```

**Resolução:** Eu somente não sabia que era padrão colocar /api para Rest.

Comment: Olá, Remova o group que está dentro do group e no get coloque: "ponto" no lugar da / Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Onde você definiu essa rota?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução é simples. Tente isso:
   http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/api/ponto/

Mas vem aquela pergunta, por que isso?
A resposta também é simples: Se você olhar no Provider que registra as rotas: RouteServiceProvider, no método mapApiRoutes, perceberá que já há um prefixo chamado api, para rotas que estejam no arquivo api.php, portanto não é necessário definir um prefixo api novamente no seu arquivo de rotas.